# How can I check to see if ints and decimals are valid?

Tags: c#

I have this code that checks to see if the user entered anything into the textboxes, but I don't know the equivelant to check the other textboxes that are int's and decimals.

```
public bool IsValid
        {
            get
            {
                return (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StreetName) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(City) && HouseNumber != null  );
            }
        }
```

And of course the Housenumber != null part has a squiggly underline. HouseNumber is a decimal and I need to check a few that are ints too, so what can I replace HouseNumber != null with?

It would be so awesome if I could do this

```
             public bool IsValid
            {
                get
                {
                    return (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StreetName) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(City) && !Decimal.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HouseNumber)  );
                }
            }
```

Comment: Value types cannot be null.  What does "valid" mean? How are they being set?

Comment: The user enters the info into wpf textboxes, and once all the textboxes have something in them, the save button is enabled. Right now the save button is enabled when the user enters something into the streetname and city textboxes, but I don't want it to be enabled until all of the textboxes are filled.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that textboxes geneally deal with text.  Are you looking for the `TryParse` methods on `int` and `decimal` data types?

Comment: Possibly. I want this to work !Decimal.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HouseNumber), but since that won't work since it is not a reference type, I want something that will work. Please.

Comment: I have not seen the `@@` syntax before. What is that supposed to be doing?

Comment: Just a hint: Your application will face problems with housenumbers in other countries. I have seen housenumbers like: 9/1 or 9a, 9b ...

Answer (score 1):

`HouseNumber` can never be `null` because it is a value type.  `default(decimal)` is `0`.  So, if `0` is always an invalid number, then check for that.  If it is a valid number you can initialize it to something invalid, i.e.,

```
class Whatever
{
    private const decimal InvalidHouseNum = decimal.MinValue;

    public Whatever(...)
    {
        // ...
        HouseNumber = InvalidHouseNum;
    }
    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            return (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StreetName) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(City) && HouseNumber != InvalidHouseNum  );
        }
    }

}
```

If *any* number is valid, use a nullable decimal, i.e.,

```
private decimal? HouseNumber { get; set; }
```

Now it will be null by default.

---

As an aside; is a `decimal` really the best choice for a house number?  Can a house number have a fractional part?

---

Edit: Just read your comment.  If `HouseNumber` is actually a string (not a `decimal` as you said in your question), then use `TryParse`.  Of course, you probably should be using a control which doesn't allow invalid values in the first place.

Comment: I once lived in a house with a house number of 935 1/2. It was a bit odd though.

Comment: Hmmm this would work. I wonder if there's a better way though where I don't have to create new variables, since I didn't have to create new variables for the other two that I'm checking. Less code is better.

Comment: @jordanhill 1. I hope you get back soon from injury. 2. That's why I made it a decimal, so people could put 935.5.

Comment: Ithink `TryParse()` just returns `false` if the string is unparsable. It isn't `Parse()'

Comment: @jordanhill - Just a coincidence apparently. I'm a big Lakers fan and they have a player named Jordan Hill who is pretty good. I hope he gets back soon. Figured you were a fan or something.

Comment: So far I like this answer best. I'd rather add a new variable than add a new method. If nothing better comes along, it's what I'm going with. Thanks for the help. My decimal is already nullable too.

Comment: @Brad: Yeah, iirc I was going to explain what `TryParse` does, and then I was distracted.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of methods:

```
    public bool isDecimal(string s)
    {
        Decimal d;
        return Decimal.TryParse(s, out d);
    }
    public bool isInt(string s)
    {
        int i;
        return Int32.TryParse(s, out i);
    }
```

**Edit:**

```
    public bool isNullWhiteSpaceAndNotDecimal(string s)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
        {
            return true;
        }
        Decimal d;
        return !Decimal.TryParse(s, out d);
    }
    public bool isNullWhiteSpaceAndNotInt(string s)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
        {
            return true;
        }
        int i;
        return !Int32.TryParse(s, out i);
    }
```

This goes more along the lines of what you wanted like this `!Decimal.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HouseNumber);`

Comment: What I meant by that was I wanted some sort of small amount of code, possibly utilizing the FCL that I could just insert right there in the return statement. This answer is definitely a right one, and I appreciate the help. In the future, I might find its best to just create those methods, but for this one I'm just going with less code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for some reason, my textboxes are populated with 0's, so this ended up working for me where those other answers didn't work.

```
public bool IsValid
        {
            get
            {
                return (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StreetName) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(City) && HouseNumber != 0 && ZipCode != 0 && Price != 0);
            }
        }
```

I'm still very novice at C# so it didn't occur to me that I also probably could've just added a .ToString() if any of the decimal or int textboxes were empty, like below. It got rid of the red squiggly underline, but since the textboxes have 0's I used the above version and it worked. The answer below is what I was looking for at the time though.

```
public bool IsValid
        {
            get
            {
                return (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StreetName) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(City) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HouseNumber.ToString) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ZipCode.ToString) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Price.ToString) );
            }
        }
```